# Riemann-Stieltjes integral of a monotonic function zero

Tags: real-analysis

This is a question from the exercises of Apostol's Mathematical Analysis book (Chapter 7 on Riemann-Stieltjes integration):
Suppose on $[a,b]$, $f$ is Riemann-Stieltjes integrable with respect to some $\alpha$ and the integral iz zero when $f$ monotonic. That is, $\int_a^b f \,d\alpha=0$. Then prove that $\alpha$ is a constant on this interval. How can we do this?

Comment: You haven't been a member long, so I want to be sure you know that you are supposed to show your own attempt at the problem.  However, to get you started, look at the function f(x) = x on [-1,1] and construct the Riemann-Stieljes sum using $\alpha(x_{i+1})-\alpha(x_i)$.  Can you set up $\alpha$ so that this sum does not tend to 0 as the partition gets finer?